# Crystal Report Design : Group some rows into one

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report, reportviewer

I have some tables in the DB.
One of my reports use the result table of an inner join, like this:

```
id    date    column 1   column 2    column 3
---------------------------------------------
 1  2012/3/15   data       data        data
 1  2012/3/15   data       data        data
 1  2012/3/15   data       data        data
---------------------------------------------
 2  2012/3/18   data       data        data
 2  2012/3/18   data       data        data
 2  2012/3/18   data       data        data
```

But I want to show them like below in my report viewer:

```
id    date    column 1   column 2    column 3
---------------------------------------------
 1  2012/3/15   data       data        data
                data       data        data
                data       data        data
---------------------------------------------
 2  2012/3/18   data       data        data
                data       data        data
                data       data        data
```

My steps to create report are:

1. Add > New Item > Crystal Report
2. Choosing tables > Adding fields I want to display
3. Setting "id" field for grouping
4. Finishing the wizard

I'm sure that query is correct. But the result is empty report! Here is my code :

```
string command = 
"SELECT tbl_1.id as id, tbl_1.date as date, tbl2.column1 as column1, tbl3.column2 as column2, tbl3.column3 as column3 " +
"FROM tbl_3 INNER JOIN tbl_2 ON ...";
rpt1.SetDataSource(MyClasse.GetDataTable(command));
// return of GetDataTable is an instance of .Net DataTable type
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt1;
```

When I fetch data from one table(instead of INNER JOIN's result) and use from another report rpt2, all things are correct!

How can I do this?

If there is any tutorial or similar question on StackOverflow please notify me. I'm using C#, if there is any code in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: i'm trying this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142064/Step-by-Step-Creation-of-Crystal-Report-using-its
this looks like helpful to me.

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad I read above article, but there is no helpful guide about my problem. :(

Comment: When you run the same query in database, are you getting any data?

Comment: @Siva : Yes of course!